# Is there any way to prevent the current CMD input being erased by a blank history suggestion?

Tags: windows, command-line, cmd.exe, command-history

In the CMD interpreter on Windows, the <kbd>↑</kbd> arrow key replaces the current input (not sure what the accurate term is) with commands in the command history; commands that have previously been executed.

An odd idiosyncrasy of CMD is that on a fresh instance, *when there are no previous commands in the history*, the accidental pressing of the Up arrow key replaces the current input with the last "command" in the history; nothing, essentially clearing the input:

[image]

[image]

What's more, pressing the <kbd>↓</kbd> key doesn't return the previous command as you would expect; it's permanently lost. Essentially then, in the command prompt, the Up arrow doubles as a "clear input" key.

Can this be fixed at all?

Comment: great question..  I guess that must've happened to me too.. i never really tried to apply any solution to it though.. this isn't an answer but sometimes it can be worth doing ctrl-c before the up.. or if somebody else is viewing your screen or you want to copy/paste it then `::` or `rem` before the command then enter.  You could then only do up when it's blank..(apart from 2nd/3rd... ups) but yeah if you hit up by accident while you have stuff at the command line, you lose that stuff, great point. There are some cmd replacements you might prefer, but I don't know if they resolve that issue.

Comment: again not really an answer but there is also f7 you could use for command history.

Comment: @barlop <f7> does nothing in a new cmd shell, and also won't store any command until it is executed.

Comment: @DavidPostill  I just did F7 on windows 7 cmd.exe , it a)makes a gui pop up with a list of commands and b)doesn't immediately delete what you have typed.  So if you hit F7 and may even navigate through with arrow keys, thinking but don't choose anything and just hit escape then you still have what you typed.

Comment: @barlop OP is referring to a "**a fresh instance, when there are no previous commands in the history**" (as was my comment to you above)

Comment: @DavidPostill   ok f7 does nothing there, but then the ideal would be if it did nothing(that is what one may want of up arrow), as one wouldn't want it to do something destructive, and an accidental hit of F7 will do no harm in that situation, as it will do nothing. Granted he's asking re up arrow, but it's worth noting that F7 performs the same kind of function but with a gui, and it doesn't have the issue of immediately replacing what was written on the command line if accidentally pushed..

Comment: @barlop Yeah, he wants up arrow to nothing in a new command window - I suppose it it is easier to accidentally hit up arrow than f7..

Comment: @DavidPostill so I said, "not really an answer but there is also f7".

Answer (score 1):

You could try adding [Clink](http://mridgers.github.io/clink) to your environment. It has a feature "History persistence between sessions" and from my testing (I typed a long command, did not execute it, pressed the up key and then the down) it displayed the last used command and the brought back the long command I'd typed.

Answer (score 0):

Not much to do with it if we can not alter the functions of the dos console but for my use when I write long lines or complicated things at least, I take notes in some sort of a notepad.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! This is really a comment and **not** an answer to the original question. You can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment). Please read [Why do I need 50 reputation to comment? What can I do instead?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/214174)